# Trouble properly updating React.js state

Tags: reactjs

I'm struggling to understand how React is functioning. I'm making a youtube previewer, but I cannot figure out how to make the Display component show the first result on the list every time a new searchQuery is passed. Here's my code(I know I've duplicated a lot of code as well, but a left that for now):

```js
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      searchQuery: 'technology',
      results: [],
      currentVideo: ''
    };
    this.searchVideos = this.searchVideos.bind(this);
    this.getData = this.getData.bind(this);
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  getData() {
    axios
      .get(`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&maxResults=20&order=rating&q=${this.state.searchQuery}&key=${APIkey}`)
      .then(res => {
        let results = res.data.items.map(item => {
          return item;
        })
        this.setState({results: results, currentVideo: results[0].id.videoId});
      });
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.getData();
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    axios
      .get(`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&maxResults=20&order=rating&q=${this.state.searchQuery}&key=${APIkey}`)
      .then(res => {
        let results = res.data.items.map(item => {
          return item;
        })
        this.setState({results});

      });
  }

  searchVideos() {
    let searchQuery = this.refs.searchQuery.refs.searchQuery.value;
    this.setState({searchQuery});
  }

  handleClick(video) {
    this.setState({currentVideo: video.id.videoId});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
          <Search onChange={this.onChangeEvent} searchVideos={this.searchVideos} ref="searchQuery" />
        </div>
        <div className="row">
          <Display currentVideo={this.state.currentVideo} />
          <VideoList handleClick={this.handleClick} videos={this.state.results} />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: change `componentWillMount()` for `componentDidMount()` and tell me if that works for you. You should use `componentDidMount()` when fetching data.

Comment: Is this a typo: 
this.refs.searchQuery.refs.searchQuery.value

Comment: Please read this: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Comment: Changing componentWillMount() to componentDidMount(), as I expected, didn't change anything. I am able to get the first video when the component is mounted with either of them. What I cannot figure out is how to achieve the same with every subsequent search.

this.refs.searchQuery.refs.searchQuery.value is not a typo - I'm referring to the ref inside on the input element inside the Search component.